# how to access a child node firebase nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hello I have a data like this in my firebase database
[image]

I want to access the sender name.

Here is my code

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('chat');

ref.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
   var newPlayer = data.val();
   var key = data.key;
   console.log(key);


});
```

`data.key` gives me the key `1-5`. I want to access the value for example which is `sender_name` under `1-5`. I don't know how can I do that. I have done something like this

```
var newPlayer = data.val();
console.log(newPlayer[key]['sender_name'];
```

But I got an undefined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child elements of `chat` node are `1-5`, `6-10`, etc. keys, **not** chat items, based on the data structure you show.

Firebase `child_added` event is only fired on direct children.

If you wish to listen to new items with `child_added` listener, you can:

1. Listen on each `chat/1-5`, `chat/6-10`, etc, for added children, but I understand this is not very convenient

Example to always listen to `1-5` children:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('chat/1-5');

ref.on("child_added", function(data) {
   var item = data.val();
   console.log('New message', item['sender_name'], item.text);
});
```

And a generic solution if you don't know what is the first key but you know it starts with '1-':

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('chat');
var firstKey = null

ref.on("child_added", function(data) {
   // If first key is what you are looking for 
   // and changed (or is null) update item listener
   if (data.key.startsWith('1-') && data.key !== firstKey) {
      // But first remove previous listener if present
      firstKey && ref.child(firstKey).off("child_added", checkItemsAdded)
      firstKey = data.key
      ref.child(firstKey).on("child_added", checkItemsAdded)
   }
});

function checkItemsAdded(data) {
   var item = data.val();
   console.log('New message', item['sender_name'], item.text);
}
```

And even more generic, listen to all intermediary keys (if you don't know what they are):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('chat');

ref.on("child_added", function(data) {
   // function checkItemsAdded is the same as above
   ref.child(firstKey).on("child_added", checkItemsAdded)
});
```

Note that this code listens to *all* sub keys like `1-5`, etc. So if there are just a few, or a few dozen, I would say it is OK, but I would not advise to scale this above a few hundreds.

Other (recommended) option:

2. Change data structure in a way that all items are directly written as `chat` direct children. (Remove `1-5`, `6-10` level)

Comment: hello how can I listen last added or updated keys which is 1-5 or 1-6?

Comment: added a generic option if you don't know first key for sure

Comment: hello Thank you for your detailed explanation. but I also don't know what would be the keys. since basically these 1-2 2-4 are the ids of two users who are chatting with each other. so I can't predict the ids

Comment: Edited answer again with generic listeners of all keys. But note that the code will get literally all new items from all children. Which, I guess, is what you want if you don't know user ids...

Answer (score 0):

As @Pandaiolo explains, the `child_added` events fires for direct children of the location you listen to. For each child it gives you a snapshot of all data under that child. So your `data` parameter contains all the information you're looking for. You just need to loop over it, to get one level deeper into the JSON with:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('chat');

ref.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
  var newPlayer = data.val();
  console.log(data.key);
  data.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key, child.child("sender_name").val());
  });
});
```

This will print all sender names.